# Добавление круга к Path

Tags: wpf, path

Имеется описание пути

```
<Path x:Name="PlayImage" Data="M 5,0 L 15,6 5,10 Z" Width="20" Height="10"
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Как добавить к поверх него круг не меняя Data ?
типа <pathgeometry ...
Есть такая возможность (не могу найти)?

Answer (score 0):

В результате я остановился на варианте:

```
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Height="26" Width="26">
                            <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Height="26" Width="26"  StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Gray"/>
                        </Canvas>
                        <Path Data="{StaticResource Random}" Fill="White"
                          Height="12" Width="12" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="5"/>
                    </Grid>
```